# how to resolve hibernate mapping exception

Tags: java, hibernate

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hiberPack.Lab1Client1.main(Lab1Client1.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Resource: com/jlcindia/hibernate/Customer.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:442)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1381)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1353)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1335)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1302)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1230)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1216)
    at com.hiberPack.CHibernateUtil.<clinit>(CHibernateUtil.java:10)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: so i should save the hibernate.cfg.xml and customer.hbm.xml inside the package or in src folder

Answer (score 0):

Your `Customer.hbm.xml` and `log4j.properties` are both missing. 
You have to place those files in your classpath, for example in your resources folder